# What distinction are we making in the 'economics' and 'economy' tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I'm looking at two particular tags on this site: [economics](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) and [economy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy).  Perusing the list of questions for each, I'm not seeing any clear difference between them.

Should these two tags be merged?

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, I think [economics](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) should be about the history of *economics as a discipline*, similar to [science](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science). Then [economy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy) could be about economic history, i.e. *the economic situation in the past*.

On the other hand, a cursory examination of the questions suggests the two tags seem largely redundant as they are currently used.

Comment: Last paragraph is the operative one, I think. It wouldn't be very hard to think up a reason there could be a useful difference between any two near synonyms. However, if people are just picking between them more or less randomly, that isn't useful.

Comment: The distinction is narrow enough that I'm not sure it is a useful one. I would personally tag a question about the economic events in the past with [tag:economics], and if I posted a question about the history of economics as a discipline, I might add a tag for [tag:philosophy], [tag:politics], [tag:capitalism], [tag:communism], etc. based on the context of the question.